# Portable byte order conversion

Tags: c, integer, bitwise, portability

I'm trying to improve the portability of a file format converter, specifically to POSIX platforms other than Linux. I'd appreciate a review of the following functions used for converting between little endian and host endian 32bit unsigned integers and back. This is basically to replace `le32toh` and `htole32` on platforms where they are not available. I'd particularly appreciate comments on whether this violates strict aliasing, I believe accessing integers through a char pointer is allowed but I'm not 100% sure.

I am intentionally writing endian-neutral code, performance is not so critical and simplicity, reusability and portability are more important to me. Determining endianness at compile time [is difficult across compilers and operating systems](https://sourceforge.net/p/predef/wiki/Endianness/), runtime checks either incur their own overhead if they need to be run on each function call or require a global variable.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

uint32_t
le_u32_to_cpu(uint32_t le32)
{
    unsigned char   *b = (unsigned char *)&le32;
    uint32_t    cpu_u32 = b[0] | \
          (b[1] << 8) | \
          (b[2] << 16) | \
          (b[3] << 24);

    return (cpu_u32);
}

uint32_t
cpu_to_le_u32(uint32_t cpu_u32)
{
    uint32_t    le_u32;
    unsigned char   *b = (unsigned char *)&le_u32;

    b[0] = cpu_u32 & 0xff;
    b[1] = (cpu_u32 >> 8) & 0xff;
    b[2] = (cpu_u32 >> 16) & 0xff;
    b[3] = (cpu_u32 >> 24) & 0xff;

    return (le_u32);
}

int
main(void)
{
    uint32_t    x;
    unsigned char   *b = (unsigned char *)&x;

    b[0] = 0x11;
    b[1] = 0x22;
    b[2] = 0x33;
    b[3] = 0x44;

    puts("little endian");
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%02x\n", b[i]);
    }
    printf("0x%" PRIx32 "\n", x);

    puts("cpu endianness");
    x = le_u32_to_cpu(x);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%02x\n", b[i]);
    }
    printf("0x%" PRIx32 "\n", x);

    puts("back to little endian");
    x = cpu_to_le_u32(x);
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("%02x\n", b[i]);
    }
    printf("0x%" PRIx32 "\n", x);

    return (0);
}
```

Comment: why not use unions?

Comment: well, why use unions, can you please elaborate the advantages of one over the other?

Comment: AIUI if one of the types you're reinterpreting is not `unsigned char`, then the union would be necessary to avoid strict aliasing issues. `float`->`uint32_t` or `double` -> `uint64_t` would need a union. But `unsigned char` is the one *escape valve* type that allows pointer-punning for a reinterpretation of the stored object. ... Using a union might be better style since it extends to other conversions not involving `unsigned char`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Very good that functions signatures use unsigned types.
2. Simplify code: If the routines are only called when the endian is backwards (Assume only big and little endian exist, no mixed endian), use the following and macro detection.  For endian test, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2100385/2410359).

   ```
   uint32_t endian_reverse32(uint32_t le32) {
     return ((le32 &       0xFF) < 24) | \
            ((le32 &     0xFF00) <  8) | \
            ((le32 &   0xFF0000) >  8) | \
            ((le32 & 0xFF000000) > 24);
   }

   #if ENDIANNESS == LITTLE
     #define le_u32_to_cpu(u32) ((uint32_t) u32)
     #define cpu_to_le_u32(u32) ((uint32_t) u32)
   #else
     #define le_u32_to_cpu(u32) endian_reverse32(u32)
     #define cpu_to_le_u32(u32) endian_reverse32(u32)
   #endif
   ```
3. Else important: optimize code for platforms that do not need any endian adjustment: [@JSY](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/121715/29485).
   Cast result to insure consistent return type (or make `inline()`

   ```
   #define le_u32_to_cpu(x) ((uint32_t)x)
   #define cpu_to_le_u32(x) ((uint32_t)x)
   ```
4. Include routines to handle 16-bit and 64-bit.
5. `0xff` mask not needed.  If anything, to quiet conversion warnings use cast.

   ```
   // b[1] = (cpu_u32 >> 8) & 0xff;
   b[1] = cpu_u32 >> 8;

   // quiet some warnings.
   b[1] = (uint8_t)(cpu_u32 >> 8);
   ```
6. "I'd particularly appreciate comments on whether this violates strict aliasing... ".  I do not believe it does.  A simple solution is to use a `union`

   ```
   uint32_t le_u32_to_cpu(uint32_t le32) {
     union {
       uint32_t u32;
       uint8_t b[4];
     } u = { le32 };

     uint32_t cpu_u32 =   u.b[0] | \
         ((uint32_t) b[1] <<  8) | \
         ((uint32_t) b[2] << 16) | \
         ((uint32_t) b[3] << 24);
     return cpu_32;
   }
   ```
7. Style: Parens around return value are not needed.
8. Pedantic: use `uint8_t`.  `unsigned char` *could* be 16-bit or wider.  Better to fail the compilation if `uint8_t` does not exist.

   ```
   uint8_t *b = (uint8_t *)&le32;
   ```
9. Pedantic: Should your wonderful code get ported to a place when `unsigned` is < 32 bit, only takes a little more to insure that portability.

   ```
   uint8_t *b = (uint8_t *)&le32;
   uint32_t cpu_u32 = b[0] | \
     ((uint32_t)b[1] << 8) | \
     ((uint32_t)b[2] << 16) | \
     ((uint32_t)b[3] << 24);
   ```

Final: Note, for maximum portability, code could even run on a 36-bit or 64-bit `unsigned` machine.  Just swap 8-bit bytes of least 32-bits, zeroing out any more significant ones.  No need for aliasing, pointers, etc.

```
    uint32least_t endian_reverse32(uint32least_t le32) {
      return (uint32least_t) (
          ((le32 &       0xFFu) < 24) | \
          ((le32 &     0xFF00u) <  8) | \
          ((le32 &   0xFF0000u) >  8) | \
          ((le32 & 0xFF000000u) > 24));
    }

    #if ENDIANNESS == LITTLE
      #define le_u32_to_cpu(u32) ((uint32least_t) (u32 & 0xFFFFFFFF))
      #define cpu_to_le_u32(u32) ((uint32least_t) (u32 & 0xFFFFFFFF))
    #else
      #define le_u32_to_cpu(u32) endian_reverse32(u32)
      #define cpu_to_le_u32(u32) endian_reverse32(u32)
    #endif
```

Comment: There are still microprocessor on which an unaligned memory access causes a fault. For that reason, I'd advise against the `union` approach if it's important to have truly portable code.

Comment: @Edward.  Using a `union`  _prevents_  unaligned memory access faults.  Using a union increases portability concerning alignment.  A `union` insures  all fields are properly aligned.  I am very familiar with this fault you speak of.

Comment: Regarding 2. & 3.: see my edit above, 8.: POSIX guarantees that `CHAR_BITS` is 8 and I believe if `uint8_t` wouldn't be a typedef for `unsigned char` then your statement would violate strict aliasing anyway. Other that excellent comments.

Comment: @chux: Yes, you're right.  I was thinking of pointer access which I've also seen attempted for this purpose, but a `union` is indeed different.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

#### Optimize for host endianness

On a little endian host, you shouldn't have to go through all that work to convert a little endian int to a little endian int (i.e. a nop).  The tricky part is determining whether the host is little endian or not at compile time.  One way is to check `__BYTE_ORDER`, which is defined by gcc.  If your compiler does not define `__BYTE_ORDER`, you can [look at this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2100331/c-macro-definition-to-determine-big-endian-or-little-endian-machine) for alternative methods.

Here is how it could look:

```
#if !defined(__BYTE_ORDER)
# error Unknown endianness.
#endif

#if __BYTE_ORDER == __LITTLE_ENDIAN
# define le_u32_to_cpu(x) (x)
# define cpu_to_le_u32(x) (x)
#else
uint32_t
le_u32_to_cpu(uint32_t le32)
{
    unsigned char   *b = (unsigned char *)&le32;
    uint32_t    cpu_u32 = b[0] | \
          (b[1] << 8) | \
          (b[2] << 16) | \
          (b[3] << 24);

    return (cpu_u32);
}

uint32_t
cpu_to_le_u32(uint32_t cpu_u32)
{
    uint32_t    le_u32;
    unsigned char   *b = (unsigned char *)&le_u32;

    b[0] = cpu_u32 & 0xff;
    b[1] = (cpu_u32 >> 8) & 0xff;
    b[2] = (cpu_u32 >> 16) & 0xff;
    b[3] = (cpu_u32 >> 24) & 0xff;

    return (le_u32);
}
#endif
```

Comment: Actually I am intentionally writing endian-neutral code since performance is not so critical and determining endianness at compile time is messy and checking at runtime has its own issues. I will clarify my post accordingly.